# How to configure adapter in newest version of ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have just moved to `Ember 1.0.0` and `ember-data-v1.0.0-beta.1-87-gc08101e.js`. I am getting lots of trouble. For starters:

```
App.Adapter.configure('plurals', {
    voice_menu : 'voicemenus',
    profile    : 'profile',
    company    : 'companies',
});
```

I get this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object ... has no method 'configure'
```

How can I configure the Adapter now?

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366924/emberdata-1-0-0 
bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `configure` method on Adapter in the new ember data. Adapters have changed quite a bit, so you should assume that any existing customizations will need to be rewritten.

Define a custom adapter for your models like:

```
App.CompanyAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
});
```

and a custom serializer like:

```
App.CompanySerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
});
```

For details see the [rest-adapter-and-serializer-configuration](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#rest-adapter-and-serializer-configuration) section of the transition guide

Comment: According to [this link](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_pluralization-customization), it is still possible to configure plurals. Is that outdated? It would be very helpful to have the documentation split into ember and ember-data. Currently, everything is mixed up.

Comment: I don't believe the guides have been updated for ember-data v1-beta. Agreed the docs are mixed up, it is very early to be using v1-beta if you want to try it suggest sticking to the source.

Comment: Also, ember-data-beta is pretty smart about how it handles plurals out of box. See this commit for a look at how it works: https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/9325a1dea594b8ff752886eb7a9d752785282e07

Comment: Thanks Mike. I see a huge refactoring effort to move to ember data 1.0, so I will wait until it is released. A showstopper for me at the moment is the lack of embedded records support. I'll keep working with 0.13 until everything breaks down :(